# CKAN Harvester failing to load individual harvest pages

Tags: mod-wsgi, ckan

Okey Doke,

This is a CKAN Harvester issue.

I've successfully installed CKAN 2.8.1
It is served with Apache 2.4.18
I've turned off the nginx caching server
I've installed an SSL certificate 
Solr 3.6.2/Jetty 8 is functioning
PostGreSQL 9.5.14 is functioning

Then I've installed ckanext-harvest on top of a Redis 3.0.6 server. Everything seemed to load absolutely fine. The harvester Web UI comes up. It allows me to create a new harvest and all functionality with the add/search screen appears to be working.

The issue comes when I attempt to launch an individual harvest page. CKAN itself appears to be fine acting as a frame, but the page contents return a 500 Internal Server Error.

```
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.017779 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] Error - <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019248 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] URL: https://my.ckan.instance/harvest/publications-test
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019272 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/site-packages/weberror/errormiddleware.py', line 171 in __call__
```

There were several more lines here which appeared to just be following the TypeError through several functions, and I'm already over my character count.

```
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019450 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019453 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/templates/source/read.html', line 1 in top-level template code
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019457 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% extends "source/read_base.html" %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019461 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/templates/source/read_base.html', line 1 in top-level template code
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019465 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% extends "source/base.html" %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019473 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/templates/source/base.html', line 7 in top-level template code
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019478 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% set authorized_user = h.check_access('harvest_source_create') %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019481 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 1 in top-level template code
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019485 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% extends "base.html" %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019488 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/templates/base.html', line 1 in top-level template code
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019492 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% ckan_extends %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019495 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/base.html', line 108 in top-level template code
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019498 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {%- block page %}{% endblock -%}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019501 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 19 in block "page"
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019505 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {%- block content %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019509 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 22 in block "content"
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019512 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% block main_content %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019516 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 74 in block "main_content"
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019519 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% block primary %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019523 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckan/ckan/templates/page.html', line 87 in block "primary"
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019526 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% block primary_content %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019530 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/templates/source/read_base.html', line 54 in block "primary_content"
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019535 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {% block primary_content_inner %}{% endblock %}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019539 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/templates/source/read.html', line 6 in block "primary_content_inner"
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019543 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   {{ h.package_list_for_source(source.id)  }}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019546 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] File '/usr/lib/ckan/default/src/ckanext-harvest/ckanext/harvest/helpers.py', line 33 in package_list_for_source
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019550 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   owner_org =  p.toolkit.c.harvest_source.get('owner_org', '')
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019554 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019560 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] 
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019562 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] 
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019564 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] CGI Variables
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019566 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] -------------
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019569 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   AUTH_TYPE: 'cookie'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019571 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   CKAN_CURRENT_URL: '/harvest/publications-test'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019573 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   CKAN_LANG: 'en'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019575 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   CKAN_LANG_IS_DEFAULT: True
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019577 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/var/www/html'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019580 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/var/www/html'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019582 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   GATEWAY_INTERFACE: 'CGI/1.1'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019584 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_ACCEPT: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019586 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: 'gzip, deflate, br'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019589 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: 'en-GB,en;q=0.5'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019591 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: 'no-cache'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019593 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_CONNECTION: 'keep-alive'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019596 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_COOKIE: '_ga=GA1.3.1163404101.1536593766; auth_tkt="b7a04011378bdd4f41b6413907535e5b5bbab899sexylegs!userid_type=unicode"; auth_tkt="b7a04011378bdd4f41b6413907535e5b5bbab899sexylegs!userid_type=unicode"; _gid=GA1.3.1885732594.1540384463; ckan=0a65c59174d44082cc2b662c58c667927520463e0cd27365dcce49b38b92df11e1a93d55'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019599 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_HOST: 'my.ckan.instance'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019601 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_PRAGMA: 'no-cache'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019603 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_REFERER: 'https://my.ckan.instance/harvest'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019605 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS: '1'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019608 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   HTTP_USER_AGENT: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:63.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/63.0'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019610 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   PATH_INFO: '/harvest/publications-test'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019612 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   PATH_TRANSLATED: '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi/harvest/publications-test'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019615 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REMOTE_ADDR: '178.170.143.229'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019620 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REMOTE_PORT: '61260'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019622 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REMOTE_USER: u'sexylegs'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019624 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REMOTE_USER_DATA: 'userid_type=unicode'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019626 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REMOTE_USER_TOKENS: ['']
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019628 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REQUEST_METHOD: 'GET'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019631 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REQUEST_SCHEME: 'https'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019633 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   REQUEST_URI: '/harvest/publications-test'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019635 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SCRIPT_FILENAME: '/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019637 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SERVER_ADDR: 'top.secret.ip.address'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019639 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SERVER_ADMIN: '[no address given]'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019642 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SERVER_NAME: 'my.ckan.instance'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019644 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SERVER_PORT: '443'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019646 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SERVER_PROTOCOL: 'HTTP/1.1'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019648 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SERVER_SIGNATURE: '<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at my.ckan.instance Port 443</address>\\n'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019651 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SERVER_SOFTWARE: 'Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019653 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   SSL_TLS_SNI: 'my.ckan.instance'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019655 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] 
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019657 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] 
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019659 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] WSGI Variables
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019661 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] --------------
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019663 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   __no_cache__: True
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019665 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   apache.version: (2, 4, 18)
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019668 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   application: <fanstatic.publisher.Delegator object at 0x7fdf44e09490>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019670 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   beaker.cache: <beaker.cache.CacheManager object at 0x7fdf44e093d0>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019672 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   beaker.get_session: <bound method SessionMiddleware._get_session of <beaker.middleware.SessionMiddleware object at 0x7fdf44e09350>>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019675 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   beaker.session: {'_accessed_time': 1540563003.924279, '_creation_time': 1540529664.548382}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019677 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   ckan.app: 'pylons_app'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019679 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   fanstatic.needed: <fanstatic.core.NeededResources object at 0x7fdf44b0b8d0>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019687 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.application_group: 'my.ckan.instance|'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019690 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.callable_object: 'application'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019692 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.daemon_connects: '1'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019694 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.daemon_restarts: '0'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019696 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.daemon_start: '1540563003887410'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019699 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.enable_sendfile: '0'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019701 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.handler_script: ''
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019703 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.input_chunked: '0'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019705 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.listener_host: ''
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019707 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.listener_port: '443'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019709 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.process_group: 'ckan_default'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019711 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.queue_start: '1540563003887238'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019714 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.request_handler: 'wsgi-script'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019716 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.request_start: '1540563003887070'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019718 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.script_reloading: '1'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019720 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.script_start: '1540563003887475'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019722 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   mod_wsgi.version: (4, 3, 0)
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019726 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   paste.cookies: (<SimpleCookie: _ga='GA1.3.1163404101.1536593766' _gid='GA1.3.1885732594.1540384463' auth_tkt='b7a04011378bdd4f41b6413907535e5b5bbab899sexylegs!userid_type=unicode' ckan='0a65c59174d44082cc2b662c58c667927520463e0cd27365dcce49b38b92df11e1a93d55'>, '_ga=GA1.3.1163404101.1536593766; auth_tkt="b7a04011378bdd4f41b6413907535e5b5bbab899sexylegs!userid_type=unicode"; auth_tkt="b7a04011378bdd4f41b6413907535e5b5bbab899sexylegs!userid_type=unicode"; _gid=GA1.3.1885732594.1540384463; ckan=0a65c59174d44082cc2b662c58c667927520463e0cd27365dcce49b38b92df11e1a93d55')
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019729 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   paste.registry: <paste.registry.Registry object at 0x7fdf44aa3310>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019732 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   paste.throw_errors: True
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019734 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   pylons.action_method: <bound method PackageController.read of <ckan.controllers.package.PackageController object at 0x7fdf44842b50>>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019737 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   pylons.controller: <ckan.controllers.package.PackageController object at 0x7fdf44842b50>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019739 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   pylons.environ_config: {'session': 'beaker.session', 'cache': 'beaker.cache'}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019754 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   pylons.pylons: <pylons.util.PylonsContext object at 0x7fdf44842650>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019757 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   pylons.routes_dict: {'action': u'read', 'controller': u'package', 'id': u'publications-test'}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019759 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   repoze.who.api: <repoze.who.api.API object at 0x7fdf449ad4d0>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019762 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   repoze.who.identity: <repoze.who identity (hidden, dict-like) at 140596914222616>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019764 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   repoze.who.logger: <logging.Logger object at 0x7fdf44e58810>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019767 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   repoze.who.plugins: {'ckan.lib.authenticator:UsernamePasswordAuthenticator': <ckan.lib.authenticator.UsernamePasswordAuthenticator object at 0x7fdf44e58750>, 'friendlyform': <FriendlyFormPlugin 140596910326416>, 'auth_tkt': <CkanAuthTktCookiePlugin 140596910326352>}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019769 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   routes.route: <routes.route.Route object at 0x7fdf450e0f10>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019772 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   routes.url: <routes.util.URLGenerator object at 0x7fdf44879110>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019774 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   webob._parsed_query_vars: (GET([]), '')
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019776 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   webob.adhoc_attrs: {'response': <Response at 0x7fdf44879450 200 OK>, 'language': 'en-us'}
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019778 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   wsgi process: 'Multi process AND threads (?)'
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019781 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   wsgi.file_wrapper: <type 'mod_wsgi.FileWrapper'>
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019783 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139]   wsgiorg.routing_args: (<routes.util.URLGenerator object at 0x7fdf44879110>, {'action': u'read', 'controller': u'package', 'id': u'publications-test'})
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.019786 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] [remote 178.170.143.229:23139] ------------------------------------------------------------
[Fri Oct 26 14:10:04.083878 2018] [wsgi:error] [pid 8201:tid 140597204223744] 2018-10-26 14:10:04,083 INFO  [ckan.lib.base]  /harvest/publications-test render time 0.063 seconds
```

So, I have limited knowledge of server thingymabobs, but this is a whole lot of error which essentially seems to be saying that somethign has gone wrong with my mod_wsgi. Now I've uninstalled, reinstalled, newest version, then back to the original version. And everything I have found in stack overflow to wrangle a different way to approach this component. IN every iteration the whoel server will come down returning a 500 error. Only the original version of mod_wsgi setup in as per the instructions seems to work serving the website (with the exception of the content of an individual harvest page).

Reading the error as best I could I've noticed:

```
TypeError: get() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

However, the line before presumably shows the call that generated this error and it only has two arguments:

```
owner_org =  p.toolkit.c.harvest_source.get('owner_org', '')
```

The gather_consumer and fetch_consumer logs appear to be clean just capturing when I registered the two actions.

I'd absolutely love oen of those fixes where someone comes on and says you jsut need to run this command to unblock a port or a user or what have you, but I'm not feeling that lucky.

I guess what I'm looking for is the next series of actions I can take to debug this 500 error and move towards getting harvester up and running.

Thanks

I was doing some more digging and found that when I tested the harvester plugin with:

```
nosetests --reset-db --ckan --with-pylons=test-core.ini ckanext/harvest/tests
```

I got this response:

```
conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "ckan_default"
```

I thought I was onto something. I've checked the password in both the .ini file and the data base and can predictably control the website's ability to talk to the database. But no combination I could think of amoungst changing the password and playing aroudn with the pg_hba.conf file allowed me to see the individual Harvest page.

Answer (score 0):

This stemmed from an incompatibility between CKAN 2.8.1 and ckanext-harvest. Harvester was updated and the problem disappeared.